# Error trying to drop a database using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying drop a possible database (if exists), and create a new one. But got some errors using [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).

I'm using a class called 'Repository' to execute my code, and all my database information is on `__init__(self):` function.

`__init__(self):`

```
def __init__(self):
    file_name = 'Repositories.json'
    json_file = open(file_name)
    self.json_data = json.load(json_file)

    self.configuration = Configuration.Config()
    self.database_host,self.database_user,self.database_password = self.configuration.get_database()
    database_connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.database_host, user = self.database_user, passwd = self.database_password)
    self.database = database_connect.cursor()
```

Function:

```
def create_database(self,repository,repository_host): 
    database_name = repository + '_' + repository_host
    database_drop_query = 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ' + str(database_name)
    database_create_query = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + str(database_name)
    self.database.execute(database_drop_query)
    self.database.execute(database_create_query)
    self.database.close()
    return database_name
```

Error:

```
  File "Repository.py", line 46, in create_database
    self.database.execute(database_drop_query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 154, in execute
    db = self._get_db()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 136, in _get_db
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, "cursor closed")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: cursor closed
```

I am unable to interpret this error, or find a possible solution . Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Please show where you call the function `create_database` that is causing the error

Comment: database_name = self.create_database(repository,repository_host)

Comment: It's called in another function, where I'll use the database_name string value.

Comment: I see, I got confused because I don't set up my database connection in `__init__`.  That is where you need to debug, it seems that you don't have an open connection.

Comment: Oh, I'll try to do mine connection inside the function and see if it works. Thanks in advance.